# app bundle in /Users/deepika/Downloads/abc.app does not seem to be properly linked with Calabash.

Tags: ios, testing, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I m trying to just launch the application on simulator and it always gives me following exception.

System.Exception:app bundle in /Users/deepika/Downloads/abc.app does not seem to be properly linked with Calabash. Please verify that it includes the Calabash component.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Xamarin.UITest;
using Xamarin.UITest.iOS;
using Xamarin.UITest.Queries;

namespace XamarinTestttt
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        iOSApp app;

        [SetUp]
        public void BeforeEachTest ()
        {




            app = ConfigureApp
                .iOS
                .DeviceIdentifier("093F1EB8-F87B-4A7E-8D18-EBC1F78DE66F")
                .AppBundle(@"/Users/deepik/Downloads/abc.app")
                .StartApp ();
        }

        [Test]
        public void AppLaunches ()
        {

            app.Repl ();
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add the `Xamarin Test Cloud Agent` Nuget to the `Xamarin.iOS` project

2) Enable the Calabash Agent when building a `DEBUG` release:

> After adding the Xamarin Test Cloud Agent to the iOS project, it is necessary to initialize the Xamarin Test Cloud Agent when the iOS project starts up. Edit the **`AppDelegate`** class and add the following snippet to the **`FinishedLaunching`** method:

```
// Newer version of Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio provide the
// ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD compiler directive in the Debug configuration,
// but not the Release configuration.
#if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD
Xamarin.Calabash.Start();
#endif
```

Ref: [Adding the Xamarin Test Cloud Agent to the iOS Project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/adding-uitest/#Adding_the_Xamarin_Test_Cloud_Agent_to_the_iOS_Project)